# Ratio of cream/butter to cheese in Alfredo with high fat cheeses?

Tags: sauce, italian-cuisine, dairy

I would like to substitute ricotta in Alfredo with mascarpone. However I found doing that greatly affects the texture of the Alfredo making it too greasy and less creamy and smooth like I want it to be.

What should be the butter and cream ratio to cheese when using high fat cheeses? Should you use milk to offset all the fat from the mascarpone?

Comment: Do you use ricotta (or mascarpone) in place of Parmesan cheese ? most recipes only call for butter, parmesan (and sometimes cream).

Comment: I am using the American version that is heavy with cream. While parmeggiano is for the authentic alfredo made on heated plates, it does not work well with the cooked version.